# EmailBroadcastProcessorService has leaked ServiceConnection

Tags: android

I get the following exception when calling:

`requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);`

```
2089-2089/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Service com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@10bbc6d8 that was originally bound here

android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@10bbc6d8 that was originally bound here`
```

my onCreate method looks like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_detail);

    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

}
```

I'm at a loss for where to even start with this. Anyone have any ideas?

Also just to clarify that the exception doesn't occur when the `requestWindowFeature` line is removed.

Comment: I hope this error is not related to your code. As the error message showing email service in log. Check your code and debug it to identify what happening in your code.

Comment: There is nothing in the code that should be using the email service which is why I'm so confused.

Comment: So you have to concentrate on your application functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
requestWindowFeature
```

should have been:

```
supportRequestWindowFeature
```

Although there may be some other underlying issue, I don't understand why this was the error given. It's also the same error given if in other places non support methods are used in place of support methods when using an appcompat theme