# Problems while testing hello work app in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just installed Android Studio and GenyMotion. I'm running the basic hello world app to see if anything ok, GenyMotion does not show my app and I get this error in android monitor :

```
06-18 14:27:53.440 1663-1663/com.android.email E/ActivityThread: Service com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@2e600d89 that was originally bound here
     android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@2e600d89 that was originally bound here
         at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1077)
         at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:971)
         at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1782)
         at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1765)
         at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:539)
         at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:181)
         at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:224)
         at com.android.email.service.EmailServiceUtils.isServiceAvailable(EmailServiceUtils.java:160)
         at com.android.email.provider.AccountReconciler.reconcileAccountsInternal(AccountReconciler.java:171)
         at com.android.email.provider.AccountReconciler.reconcileAccounts(AccountReconciler.java:115)
         at com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.reconcileAndStartServices(EmailBroadcastProcessorService.java:305)
         at com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.onBootCompleted(EmailBroadcastProcessorService.java:295)
         at com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.onHandleIntent(EmailBroadcastProcessorService.java:130)
         at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
06-18 14:27:53.464 1663-1700/com.android.email E/EmailServiceProxy: RuntimeException when trying to unbind from service
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@2e600d89
        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1029)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1816)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:551)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection$1.doInBackground(ServiceProxy.java:124)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection$1.doInBackground(ServiceProxy.java:111)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-18 14:27:57.793 1464-1749/com.android.providers.calendar E/SQLiteLog: (284) automatic index on view_events(_id)
06-18 14:27:59.581 712-786/system_process E/WifiStateMachine: WifiStateMachine L2Connected CMD_START_SCAN source -2 2, 3 -> obsolete
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778718/emailbroadcastprocessorservice-has-leaked-serviceconnection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079909/android-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-service-not-registered)

Comment: Literally pasted your error in google and found this. Don't be a dick, do your research before asking.